# Iterate through array and start a new array whenever a certain value is found

Tags: arrays, swift

Say i have the following array:

```
array = ["a", "b", "c", "new", "d", "e", "f", "g", "new", "h", "i", "new"]
```

I want to create a new array every time I find the value "new".

So I would end up with:

```
array1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
array2 = ["d", "e", "f", "g"]
array3 = ["h", "i"]
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you guaranteed a `"new"` at the end? What do you do if you have two `"new"` in a row, if this is allowed?

Comment: No, there may not be a `"new"` at the end. And there will never be two `"new"` in a row.

Comment: Maybe `array.split(separator: "new")` ?

Comment: @vadian That's the answer, isn't it?

Comment: Or `array.split(separator: "new").map(Array.init)` if you need "real" arrays instead of slices.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not sure if a nested array is the desired result.

Comment: @vadian That's the only general answer, though - otherwise, some trickery would be in order to deal with too many/too few "new"s in the array.

Comment: @vadian that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight By default, `split` ignores empty sub-sequences, so consecutive "new"s shouldn't be a problem in any case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name implies you can split arrays with the `split` function, however that returns `ArraySlice` objects.

To get arrays back from the slices you need to `map` them (credits to Martin R)

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "new", "d", "e", "f", "g", "new", "h", "i", "new"]
let splittedArrays = array.split(separator: "new").map(Array.init)
```